# Is it possible to use bubbling method for document events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

I know that if you create div inside div and let them call one function onclick event, it suppose to call the last one, and then the first and you can easily control this with canceling bubbling method and so on.

It's not happen with events I add to the document. For example I have a dialog and an overlay opened, I wish to close them with pressing 'Escape', but it always first closes the dialog, and then the overlay, which is kind of weird. I want to close my overlay and stop, but it seems unreal now for me. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Tried using methods like capture or stop bubbling, but it always goes the same

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function closingChat(e){
            if(event.key === 'Escape')
            console.log('im closing chat')
        }

        function closingOverlay(e){
            if(event.key === 'Escape')
            console.log('im closing overlay')
        }

        function closingChatClick(){
            console.log('im closing chat with click')
        }

        function closingOverlayClick(){
            console.log('im closing OVERlay with click')
        }
        document.addEventListener('keydown',closingChat)
        document.addEventListener('keydown',closingOverlay)
    </script>
    <div onclick="closingChatClick()">
        <p onclick="closingOverlayClick()">heY</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code executes in the order you mentioned, this has nothing to do with `event bubbling`.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',closingChat)
document.addEventListener('keydown',closingOverlay)
```

`keydown` event is attached to the `document`, when the key is pressed it will first execute `closingChat` function and then `closingOverlay` function.

If you want to call only `closingOverlay` remove this `document.addEventListener('keydown',closingChat)`.

```js
function closingChat(e) {
  if (event.key === 'Escape')
    console.log('im closing chat')
}

function closingOverlay(e) {
  if (event.key === 'Escape')
    console.log('im closing overlay')
}

function closingChatClick() {
  console.log('im closing chat with click')
}

function closingOverlayClick() {
  console.log('im closing OVERlay with click')
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', closingOverlay);
```

```html
<div onclick="closingChatClick()">
  <p onclick="closingOverlayClick()">heY</p>
</div>
```

Comment: example is very poor, but I have react project, where I need both events, and if Im going to remove them every time that I press one event, I have to add them back again then, this is horrible decision